# Form:select setting img src

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this form :

```
<form action="php script" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <select class="form-control" name="image" id="image" onclick='edit()' >
            <option>Image 1
            <option>Image 2
            <option>Image 3
            <option>Image 4
            <option>Image 5
            <option>Image 6
            <option>Image 7
        </select>
</form>
```

And I have this image :

```
<img id="avatar" alt="" />
```

Is it possible to conditionnaly set the *img src* with the form ?
I tried using some js, like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var imId = document.getElementById("image").src;
    document.getElementById("avatar").src = "img/av"+imId.slice(-1)+".png";
</script>
```

But it's not working... Any tip please ?

Comment: Do you wish to change the source of image on change of option in select dropdown?

Comment: You can do this easyl in jquery, or do you want to stick with your kind of solution?

Comment: Additionally, options in select dropdown does not have any value.

Comment: Options in dropdown menu don't have src attribute so your `imId` variable will return `undefined`.

Comment: What is the `src` attribute of `id=image`? Do we have at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use data attributes in your options to store the path of the image?

```
<select class="form-control" name="image" id="image">
    <option data-source="/first_path/">Image 1</option>
    <option data-source="/second_path/">Image 2</option>
    <option data-source="/third_path/">Image 3</option>
    <option data-source="/fourth_path/">Image 4</option>
    <option data-source="/fifth_path/">Image 5</option>
    <option data-source="/sixth_path/">Image 6</option>
    <option data-source="/seventh_path/">Image 7</option>
</select>
```

and then use a `change` event on the dropdown to fetch the source of the selected option.

```
$('#image').change(function(){
    var path = $(this).find('option:selected').data('source'); //get source of selected option and store it in variable path
    $('#avatar').attr('src', path); //specify image's source to be variable path
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, do following

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var avatar = $("#avatar");
    avatar.attr("src", "img/av" + avatar.attr("src").slice(-1) + ".png";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to automate applying attributes to DOM elements

```
$("#avatar").each(function(index) {    
    var titleName = $(this).attr("src").toString().split('/').splice(-1,1);
    var anchorIndex = "a:eq(" + index + ")";
    $(anchorIndex).attr("title", titleName);
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/hbgtL3p7/13/)